# Use AudioQueue to play PCM audio stream in ios, First is ok,but no voice after 15mins

Tags: ios, audio, audioqueue

I get audio data from RTMPPacket, and I use AudioQueue to play it in IPAD.
First, the voice is fine. But After about 15mins, there is no voice.
Then the data is ok, and the queue is playing.
I don't know why. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

This is my class used to play audio.

AudioPlayer.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>
#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define kNumberBuffers 3

@interface AudioPlayer : NSObject
{
AudioQueueRef                   mQueue;
AudioQueueBufferRef             mBuffers[kNumberBuffers];
AudioStreamBasicDescription     mPlayFormat;
int                             mIndex;
@public
Boolean                         mIsRunning;
Boolean                         mIsInitialized;
int                             mBufferByteSize;
int                             pip_fd[2];
UInt32                          mNumPacketsToRead;
}
@property AudioQueueRef mQueue;

-(id)init;
-(id)initWithSampleRate:(int)sampleRate;
-(void)startPlayWithBufferByteSize:(int)bufferByteSize;
-(void)stopPlay;
-(void)putAudioData:(short*)pcmData;
@end
```

AudioPlayer.m

```
#import "AudioPlayer.h"

@implementation AudioPlayer
@synthesize mQueue;

void AQBufferCallback(void *                inUserData ,
                  AudioQueueRef         inAQ,
                  AudioQueueBufferRef   inBuffer)
{
    AudioPlayer *THIS = (__bridge AudioPlayer *)(inUserData);

    if(THIS->mIsRunning)
    {
        inBuffer->mPacketDescriptionCount = THIS->mBufferByteSize/2;
        inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize =THIS->mBufferByteSize;
        if(read(THIS->pip_fd[0], inBuffer->mAudioData, THIS->mBufferByteSize) > 0 ){
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(inAQ, inBuffer, 0, NULL);
        }
    }

}

-(id)init
{
    return [self initWithSampleRate:16000];
}

-(id)initWithSampleRate:(int)sampleRate
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        memset(&mPlayFormat, 0, sizeof(mPlayFormat));
        mPlayFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
        mPlayFormat.mFormatFlags = kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked;
        mPlayFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
        mPlayFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
        mPlayFormat.mBytesPerPacket = mPlayFormat.mBytesPerFrame = (mPlayFormat.mBitsPerChannel / 8) * mPlayFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
        mPlayFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
        mPlayFormat.mSampleRate = sampleRate;
        mIsRunning = false;
        mIsInitialized = false;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)startPlayWithBufferByteSize:(int)bufferByteSize
{
    if (mIsInitialized) return;

    mBufferByteSize = bufferByteSize;
    AudioQueueNewOutput(&mPlayFormat, AQBufferCallback, (__bridge void *)(self), nil, nil, 0, &mQueue);
    for (int i=0; i<kNumberBuffers; i++) {
        AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(mQueue, mBufferByteSize,  &mBuffers[i]);
    }

    AudioQueueSetParameter(mQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, 1.0);
    mIsInitialized = true;
    int ret = pipe(pip_fd);
    if (ret == -1) {
        NSLog(@"create pipe failed");
    }
}

-(void)stopPlay
{
    close(pip_fd[0]);
    close(pip_fd[1]);
    AudioQueueStop(mQueue, false);
    if (mQueue){
    AudioQueueDispose(mQueue, true);
    mQueue = NULL;
    mIsRunning = false;
    }
    mIsInitialized = false;
    NSLog(@"stop play queue");
}

-(void)putAudioData:(short*)pcmData
{

    if (!mIsRunning) {
        memcpy(mBuffers[mIndex]->mAudioData, pcmData, mBufferByteSize);
        mBuffers[mIndex]->mAudioDataByteSize = mBufferByteSize;
        mBuffers[mIndex]->mPacketDescriptionCount = mBufferByteSize/2;
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer(mQueue, mBuffers[mIndex], 0, NULL);
        NSLog(@"fill audio queue buffer[%d]",mIndex);
        if(mIndex == kNumberBuffers - 1) {
            mIsRunning = true;
            mIndex = 0;
            AudioQueueStart(mQueue, NULL);
        }else {
        mIndex++;
        }
   }else {
        if(write(pip_fd[1], pcmData, mBufferByteSize) < 0){
            NSLog(@"write to the pipe failed!");
        }
    }
}
@end
```